# Calculating Risk Ratio: different results with different R-packages (epitools and epiR)

Tags: r, relative-risk

if someone could educate me on how R functions calculate risk ratios I would be grateful. I'm having trouble interpreting results from different packages: `epitools` and `epiR`.

Here is my example data and outputs:

```
require("epitools")
require("epiR")

tab <- matrix(c(53, 126, 197, 1437),byrow=TRUE,nrow=2)

epitab(tab,method = "riskratio")

#$tab
#          Outcome
#Predictor  Disease1        p0 Disease2        p1 riskratio    lower    upper      p.value
#  Exposed1       53 0.2960894      126 0.7039106  1.000000       NA       NA           NA
#  Exposed2      197 0.1205630     1437 0.8794370  1.249359 1.134212 1.376195 4.331952e-09

#$measure
#[1] "wald"

#$conf.level
#[1] 0.95

#$pvalue
#[1] "fisher.exact"

epi.2by2(tab, method = "cohort.count")

#             Outcome +    Outcome -      Total        Inc risk *        Odds
#Exposed +           53          126        179              29.6       0.421
#Exposed -          197         1437       1634              12.1       0.137
#Total              250         1563       1813              13.8       0.160

#Point estimates and 95% CIs:
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
#Inc risk ratio                               2.46 (1.89, 3.19)
#Odds ratio                                   3.07 (2.15, 4.37)
#Attrib risk *                                17.55 (10.68, 24.42)
#Attrib risk in population *                  1.73 (-0.51, 3.97)
#Attrib fraction in exposed (%)               59.28 (47.13, 68.64)
#Attrib fraction in population (%)            12.57 (7.34, 17.50)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
# Test that OR = 1: chi2(1) = 41.811 Pr>chi2 = <0.001
# Wald confidence limits
# CI: confidence interval
# * Outcomes per 100 population units
```

So I am confused. When I calculate the risk ratio by hand I get 2.46, which is the same as in the `epi.2by2` output described as "Inc risk ratio". Why is the risk ratio given by `epitools` 1.25 and not 2.46?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the expected structure of the data differs in the two packages.

In the case of `epitools`:

[image: epitools table structure]

In the case of `epiR`:

[image: epiR table structure]

You need to switch the *Disease* columns when using `epitab` and you will get the same results.
You can find the required data structures in the documentations:

[epitools documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/epitools/epitools.pdf), page 26.

[epiR documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/epiR/epiR.pdf), page 4.

Comment: Thanks! Makes perfect sense.